# 2 byte input will not print newline if 2 characters are entered x86_64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm writing a program where the user enters a 2 charterer input and the program will simply output the input. Simple program, but I am getting a weird bug where everything works if I input a single character, but when I input 2 characters its a little weird, take a look at my code(nasm):

```
;-------------------; SYSTEM CALLS
SYS_WRITE   equ 1   ; write to _
SYS_READ    equ 0   ; read from _
SYS_EXIT    equ 60  ; end program
;-------------------;

;-------------------;
STDIN       equ 0   ; standard input
STDOUT      equ 1   ; standard output
;-------------------;


section .bss
    inp_len equ     2       ; 2 byte for user input
    inp     resb    inp_len ; buffer for user input

section .data
    message: db "Please input a 2 digit number: "
    messageLen: equ $-message
    out: db 10, "You entered: "
    outLen: equ $-out
    done: db 10, "Done.", 10
    doneLen: equ $-done


        section .text
        global _start

_start:
        ; OUTPUT FOR ASKING FOR INPUT
        mov rax, SYS_WRITE    ; Setting system call to 1(sys_write)
        mov rdi, STDOUT       ; Setting rdi to 1(
        mov rsi, message      ; rsi for sys_write is const char *buf or
                              ;   in english, the message
        mov rdx, messageLen   ; rdx for sys_write is size_t count or in
                              ;   in engligh, the message size
        syscall               ; system call

        ; INPUT
        mov rax, SYS_READ ;
        mov rdi, STDIN    ;
        mov rsi, inp      ;
        mov rdx, inp_len  ;
        syscall

        ; OUTPUT
        mov rax, SYS_WRITE
        mov rdi, STDOUT
        mov rsi, out
        mov rdx, outLen
        syscall

        mov rax, SYS_WRITE
        mov rdi, STDOUT
        mov rsi, inp
        mov rdx, inp_len
        syscall

        mov rax, SYS_WRITE
        mov rdi, STDOUT
        mov rsi, done
        mov rdx, doneLen
        syscall

        ; SYS_EXIT SUCCESS
        mov rbx, 0        ;
        mov rax, SYS_EXIT ;
        syscall
```

My output when I enter 1 charachter:

```
Please input a 2 digit number: 1

You entered: 1

Done.
```

My output for 2 character input:

```
Please input a 2 digit number: 23

You entered: 23
Done.
```

Notice how it removes a newline, what is going on?

Comment: You enter one digit and a newline. If you enter two digits, there is no place for the newline.

Comment: It's never reading the newline in the first place from `stdin`.  Check with `strace ./a.out`.  You defined `inp_len equ  2`, limiting the buffer to not have room for the `23\n` that's available from stdin, only reading the first 2 bytes.  (And you're correctly using that size as the 3rd arg for your `read()` system call.)